# Getting pageview-level reporting with Google Analytics custom dimensions

Tags: google-analytics

I've switched from analytics.js to gtag.js and I'm having problems with reporting.

I have a number of custom dimensions set as hit-level variables (author, for instance) and have updated our code to send the gtag(event).
I see the right number of events coming in, (about 100,000 author events per 100,000 pageviews) however they no longer report with the Pageviews metric.

I see very few Author results using the Pageview metric (only a few hundred results). I'm actually seeing better Author results with the Users metric (a few thousand results, but not nearly 100,000).

Event reporting seems to be running correctly so the data is being entered into GA, but I can't seem to get the old reporting to work.

Current code set in head

```
gtag('config', GOOGLEID, { 'custom_map': {
'dimension1': 'Author', 
    'dimension2': 'Primary Taxonomy',
    'dimension3': 'Primary Type' } 
})
```

event sent near bottom of body (crna_ variables set in body)

```
gtag('event', 'set-dimensions', {
'Author': crna_author, 
'Primary Taxonomy': crna_primarytax, 
'Primary Type': crna_primarytype
 });
```

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot? Thanks.

Comment: Can't tell for sure unless you provide more examples of how you're sending the pageviews/events. When you've gone from analytics.js to gtag.js, maybe you've gone from "set" command in ga() to just sending the CDs with the hit without setting. Again, need code examples.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem - user and session custom dimensions are available in the Site Content report but hit custom dimensions are not.

I assume the initial pageview is not allocated with the custom dimensions because they are set after the pageview is recorded (via the config tag), but the instructions very clearly say this is how it should be done.

Comment: I haven't solved this but come to the understanding that you describe - the custom dimensions are sent separately from the initial pageload event, so they can only be views as 'hits' rather than correlated to pageviews. You get used to it.